# insert or update - the right way

Tags: mysql, insert-update

the working scenario on a web bases app like a forum, the users can add or edit their replays. The strategy that I've used until now was to use different form actions: one for insert and one for update.

Is this the right approach or I can use something else, which is more easy to maintain?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use an 'edit' variable with a single form.  I set the edit variable to true when editing a form, false for creating a new form.  I send this variable (in a hidden element in the form) off to the page that processes the data and that function determines whether to INSERT or UPDATE into the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one action. If primary key is not set in the request, then this is insert, otherwise it is update.

Answer (score 1):

[Insert or on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) means you can have one form, if it's got an id that is in the database it will update, otherwise it will insert.

Comment: May cause some issues when the primary key is an Auto-incremented int (use it with caution)

Comment: @apokryfos can you provide more info about possible problems?

Comment: The issue is that the LAST_INSERT_ID() function will return the AUTO_INCREMENT value even if a record is updated (which means it will not return the actual ID of the record that was matched). So if you make use of the LAST_INSERT_ID() later on just ensure that you are checking the right ID. This is mentioned in the page, its just good to point it.